# Outlook Selecting a Subfolder in the SharedMailbox using GetSharedDefaultFolder

Tags: vba, outlook

I am having trouble trying to select a subfolder in **SharedMailbox**.
 I have read a number of resources on `GetSharedDefaultFolder`. 
However, struggling to put it together correctly.
Would be really great if you could help with this.

```
Sub ListOutlookEmailInfoInExcel()
  Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim olTaskfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim olTask As Outlook.TaskItem
  Dim olItems As Outlook.Items

  Set o1NS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set o1TaskFolder = o1NS.GetSharedDefaultFolder("Shared Folder 1", _
    olFolderInbox).Folders("admin")
  Set o1Items = o1TaskFolder.Items
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first resolve the owner as described here http://www.slipstick.com/developer/working-vba-nondefault-outlook-folders/

"You can use the mailbox owner's display name, alias, or email address when resolving the recipient."

I found email address always resolves so there is no benefit in verifying that it resolves.

```vb
Sub ListOutlookEmailInfoInExcel()

    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olTaskfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olTask As Outlook.TaskItem
    Dim olItems As Outlook.Items

    Dim objOwner As Outlook.Recipient

    Set olNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set objOwner = olNS.CreateRecipient("Shared Folder 1")
    objOwner.Resolve

    If objOwner.Resolved Then
        Set olTaskFolder = olNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, _
          olFolderInbox).Folders("admin")
        Set olItems = olTaskFolder.Items
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The [GetSharedDefaultFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869575(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Namespace class accepts two parameters: a Recipient object and the FolderType value.

The [How to: Display a Shared Calendar of a Recipient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184606%28v=office.15%29.aspx) article provides the following sample code in C#:

```
private void DisplayManagerCalendar()
{
    Outlook.AddressEntry addrEntry =
         Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
    if (addrEntry.Type == "EX")
    {
        Outlook.ExchangeUser manager =
        Application.Session.CurrentUser.
            AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().GetExchangeUserManager();
        if (manager != null)
        {
            Outlook.Recipient recip =
                Application.Session.CreateRecipient(manager.Name);
            if (recip.Resolve())
            {
                try
                {
                    Outlook.Folder folder =
                       Application.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(
                          recip, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar)
                       as Outlook.Folder;
                    folder.Display();
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Could not open manager's calendar.",
                       "GetSharedDefaultFolder Example",
                       MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                       MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry not after C#

Answer (score 0):

in order to answer ArsedianIvan question, i figured out that with a sub name like "ListOutlookEmailInfoInExcel", he would be interested to save in an excel file some email information from a shared mailbox.

Here is my suggestion to do that :

Replace "Shared Folder 1" with your shared email name and
I made this script stop after 80 email but you could modify or remove as you like

```
Sub ListEmailInfoInExcel()
Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olTaskfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olTask As Outlook.TaskItem
Dim olItems As Outlook.Items
Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objOwner As Outlook.Recipient
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim Path As String
Dim RepTemp, NewRep As String
Set olNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objOwner = olNS.CreateRecipient("Shared Folder 1")
objOwner.Resolve

If objOwner.Resolved Then
    Set olTaskfolder = olNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, _
          olFolderInbox).Folders("Admin")
      
    Set olItems = olTaskfolder.Items
End If

'Print to a new excel file
Dim objExcel As Object
Dim sheet As Object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Workbooks.Add

'Create a Temp rep in the C drive if it doesn't exist
RepTemp = "C:\Temp\"
NewRep = Dir(RepTemp, vbDirectory)
If NewRep = "" Then
      MkDir RepTemp
End If

For Each olMailItem In olTaskfolder.Items
i = i + 1
            Range("G" & i).Value = i
            Range("H" & i).Value = olMailItem.Sender
            Range("I" & i).Value = olMailItem.Subject
            Range("J" & i).Value = olMailItem.ReceivedTime
            
            ' it will print only 80 email details...
            If i = 80 Then
                GoTo isenough
            End If
Next
isenough:
Path = "C:\Temp\MyNewWorkbook"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path
ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Yours,