# Outlook Selecting a Subfolder in the SharedMailbox using GetSharedDefaultFolder Automation error

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The following code is to count the number of emails in a particular `SharedMailbox` or its `subfolder`.

I am having trouble selecting a subfolder in SharedMailbox.
I have read a number of resources on GetSharedDefaultFolder including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851850/outlook-selecting-a-subfolder-in-the-sharedmailbox-using-getshareddefaultfolder).

However, struggling to put it together correctly.
Would be really great if you could help with this.

I am experiencing the following error while running the code.

> Run-time error '-2147221233 (80040010f)' Automation error

```
Sub CountInboxSubjects()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim MyFolder1 As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim MyFolder2 As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim MyFolder3 As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim propertyAccessor As Outlook.propertyAccessor
    Dim olItem As Object
    Dim dic As Dictionary
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Subject As String
    Dim val1 As Variant
    Dim val2 As Variant

    val1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("I2")
    val2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("I3")

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set olShareName = olNs.CreateRecipient("Shared_MailBox")
    Set olFldr = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox)
    MsgBox (olFldr)

    Set MyFolder1 = olFldr.Folders("Sub_Folder")
    MsgBox (MyFolder1)
    Set MyFolder2 = MyFolder1.Folders("Sub_Sub_Folder")
    MsgBox (MyFolder2)
    Set MyFolder3 = MyFolder1.Folders("Sub_Sub_Folder2")
    MsgBox (MyFolder3)


    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EPI_Data").Range("I5") = "Inbox" Then
        MyFolder = olFldr
    ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EPI_Data").Range("I5") = "Sub_Folder" Then
        MyFolder = MyFolder1
    ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EPI_Data").Range("I5") = "Sub_Sub_Folder" Then
        MyFolder = MyFolder2
    ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EPI_Data").Range("I5") = "Sub_Sub_Folder" Then
        MyFolder = MyFolder3
    End If

    Set olItem = MyFolder.Items
    'Set myRestrictItems = olItem.Restrict("[ReceivedTime]>'" & Format$("01/01/2019 00:00AM", "General Date") & "' And [ReceivedTime]<'" & Format$("01/02/2019 00:00AM", "General Date") & "'")
    Set myRestrictItems = olItem.Restrict("[ReceivedTime]>'" & Format$(val1, "General Date") & "' And [ReceivedTime]<'" & Format$(val2, "General Date") & "'")

    For Each olItem In myRestrictItems
            If olItem.Class = olMail Then
            Set propertyAccessor = olItem.propertyAccessor
            Subject = propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001E")
            If dic.Exists(Subject) Then dic(Subject) = dic(Subject) + 1 Else dic(Subject) = 1
        End If
    Next olItem

    With ActiveSheet
        .Columns("A:B").Clear
        .Range("A1:B1").Value = Array("Count", "Subject")
        For i = 0 To dic.Count - 1
            .Cells(i + 2, "A") = dic.Items()(i)
            .Cells(i + 2, "B") = dic.Keys()(i)
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

After trouble-shooting, I am aware the following step has issues.

```
Set MyFolder1 = olFldr.Folders("Sub_Folder")
MsgBox (MyFolder1)
```

I expect the msgbox will return the subfolder name but it's reporting error.

> Run-time error '-2147221233 (80040010f)' Automation error

I couldn't find out why. can anyone please help..

Comment: What do you ecpect `MsgBox (MyFolder1)` to return? First of all the syntax is not correct it should be `MsgBox MyFolder1` secondly `MyFolder1` is defined as `Outlook.MAPIFolder` object so you should specify which property of the MAPIFolder you want to output in the message box. The `MsgBox` function is waiting for a `String` not for a `MAPIFolder`.

Comment: I am expecting the msgbox return the subfolder name, it can return the name as MsgBox (olFldr) returns "Inbox"

Answer (score 0):

*Try working with Recipient email address, if recipient name then Attempt to [resolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Recipient.Resolve) Recipient against the Address Book...*

---

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim Recip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set Recip = olNs.CreateRecipient("0m3r@Email.com")
    Recip.Resolve

    If Recip.Resolved Then
        Set Inbox = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder _
                            (Recip, olFolderInbox)
    End If        

    Inbox.Display

End Sub
```

Comment: yes, it should be the recipient address, but this is not my query.

Comment: unfortunately no, I have added the recip.resolve into my code and it's not working. I believe the issues is within this line: Set MyFolder1 = olFldr.Folders("Sub_Folder")
that is reporting run time error as per my post..

Comment: @lyricZZ on MsgBox (olFldr) does that give you the correct folder name?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you must resolve a recipient's name or address against the address book before accessing shared folders.

```
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")    
    Set olShareName = olNs.CreateRecipient("Shared_MailBox")
    olShareName.Resolve
    If Recip.Resolved Then
       Set olFldr = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox)
       ...
    End If
```

But the cause of the issue with accessing a subfolder is different...

First of all, try to uncheck `Download shared folders` checkbox checked on the `Advanced tab` of your Exchange account properties dialog. See the [Detecting if ‘Download Shared Folders’ is Checked in Outlook](http://badecho.com/2011/07/detecting-if-download-shared-folders-is-checked-in-outlook/) article for more information.

Second, please take a look at the [By default, shared mail folders are downloaded in Cached mode in Outlook 2010 and Outlook 2013](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982697) article. What value do you have set for the `CacheOthersMail` key on the PC?

See [Accessing subfolders within shared mailbox](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/180c000c-524a-45dd-88fe-88b470be3597/accessing-subfolders-within-shared-mailbox?forum=outlookdev) for more information.

Comment: thanks Eugene, I have tried the following: A) unchecked Download shared folders from Advanced tab. B) I am using outlook 2013 and have created the CacheOthersMail key = 0 on my PC. C) I have also restarted my PC but the problem remains......

Answer (score 0):

even if this question is quite old, i may suggest as @Om3r did to define your shared email and your folder you want to work with in a simple if statement. You may define your shared mail by name or by email address.

```
Sub CountInboxSubjects()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olItems As Outlook.Items
Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olItem As Object


Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olShareName = olNs.CreateRecipient("0m3r@Email.com")
olShareName.Resolve

 'select a folder based on a value in cell I5
If olShareName.Resolved Then
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("I5") = "folder" Then
        Set olFldr = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, _
olFolderInbox).Folders("folder")
        Set olItems = olFldr.Items

    ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EPI_Data").Range("I5") = "Sub_Folder" Then
        Set olFldr = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, _
olFolderInbox).Folders("Sub_folder")
        Set olItems = olFldr.Items

    ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EPI_Data").Range("I5") = "Sub_Sub_Folder"  Then
        Set olFldr = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, _
olFolderInbox).Folders("Sub_Sub_Folder")
        Set olItems = olFldr.Items

    ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EPI_Data").Range("I5") = "Sub_Folder2"    Then
        Set olFldr = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, _
olFolderInbox).Folders("Sub_Sub_Folder2")
        Set olItems = olFldr.Items
    End If
End If

MsgBox ("You have " & olItems.Count & " mail in " & " the " & olFldr.Name & " 
folder"), vbInformation
    end sub
```