# Run-timer error "5" when assign Outlook Folder.items to object in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am experiencing some issues that Excel reporting

> run-timer error "5"

when assigning Outlook `Folder.items` to object.

This is a followup thread of this one. [Outlook Selecting a Subfolder in the SharedMailbox using GetSharedDefaultFolder Automation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58316128/outlook-selecting-a-subfolder-in-the-sharedmailbox-using-getshareddefaultfolder)

After the automation error is fixed, I am experiencing run time error 5, Invalid procedure call or argument while running code:
    '''Set olItem = MyFolder.Items'''

can anyone please help?!

```
Sub CountInboxSubjects()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim MyFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim MyFolder1 As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim MyFolder2 As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim MyFolder3 As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim propertyAccessor As Outlook.propertyAccessor
    Dim olItem As Object
    'Dim olItem As Outlook.Items
    Dim dic As Dictionary
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Subject As String
    Dim val1 As Variant
    Dim val2 As Variant

    val1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EPI_Data").Range("I2")
    val2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EPI_Data").Range("I3")

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set olShareName = olNs.CreateRecipient("F0400602@email.com")
    Set olFldr = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox)

    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EPI_Data").Range("I5") = "Inbox" Then
        Set MyFolder = olFldr
        MsgBox (MyFolder)
    ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EPI_Data").Range("I5") = "Feasibilities" Then
        Set MyFolder = olFldr.Folders("Feasibilities")
        MsgBox (MyFolder)
    ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EPI_Data").Range("I5") = "FNC's" Then
        Set MyFolder = olFldr.Folders("Feasibilities").Folders("FNC's")
        MsgBox (MyFolder)
    ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EPI_Data").Range("I5") = "ISAs - Actioned" Then
        Set MyFolder = olFldr.Folders("Feasibilities").Folders("ISAs - Actioned")
        MsgBox (MyFolder)
    End If

    Set olItem = MyFolder.Items
    'Set myRestrictItems = olItem.Restrict("[ReceivedTime]>'" & Format$("01/01/2019 00:00AM", "General Date") & "' And [ReceivedTime]<'" & Format$("01/02/2019 00:00AM", "General Date") & "'")
    Set myRestrictItems = MyFolder.Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime]>'" & Format$(val1, "General Date") & "' And [ReceivedTime]<'" & Format$(val2, "General Date") & "'")

    For Each olItem In myRestrictItems
            If olItem.Class = olMail Then
            Set propertyAccessor = olItem.propertyAccessor
            Subject = propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001E")
            If dic.Exists(Subject) Then dic(Subject) = dic(Subject) + 1 Else dic(Subject) = 1
        End If
    Next olItem

    With ActiveSheet
        .Columns("A:B").Clear
        .Range("A1:B1").Value = Array("Count", "Subject")
        For i = 0 To dic.Count - 1
            .Cells(i + 2, "A") = dic.Items()(i)
            .Cells(i + 2, "B") = dic.Keys()(i)
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Dim olitems as Outlook.Items or switch to set myRestrictItems = myfolder.items

the Items property Contains a collection of Outlook item objects in a folder

---

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Sub CountInboxSubjects()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application

    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim olShareName As Outlook.Recipient
    Set olShareName = olNs.CreateRecipient("email@email.com")

    Dim olFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set olFldr = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox)


    Dim myRestrictItems As Outlook.Items
    Set myRestrictItems = olFldr.Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime]>'" & Format$(val1, "General Date") & _
                                          "' And [ReceivedTime]<'" & Format$(val2, "General Date") & "'")

    Dim olItem As Object

    Dim lng As Long
    For lng = myRestrictItems.Count To 1 Step -1

        Set olItem = myRestrictItems(lng)
        If olItem.Class = olMail Then
            Debug.Print olItem.Subject
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried A) Use Dim olitems as Outlook.Items, it won't work, still give me runtime error 5 B) switch to set myRestrictItems = myfolder.items, I cannot do this as I need to use this to restrict the search within specific time frame.

Comment: @lyricZZ okay try this - remove `Set olItem = MyFolder.Items` now fix the `myRestrictItems `to

Comment: `Set myRestrictItems = MyFolder.Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime]>'" & Format$(val1, "General Date") & "' And [ReceivedTime]<'" & Format$(val2, "General Date") & "'")`

Comment: @lyricZZ let me know.

Comment: looks like it passed, but new error showed Rum-time error "91" showed.... "Object variable or with block variable not set. " I believe this caused by     "For Each olItem In myRestrictItems" while olItem not defined, I tried to replace olItem with MyFolder.Items in "For Each olItem In myRestrictItems" and it won't work. reporting error Compile error: variable required - cannot assign to this expression.

Comment: Do you still have dim olitem as object?

Comment: after I Dim olItem As Outlook.Items, error Run-time error "13" type mismatch shown..

Comment: I switched back to Dim olItem As Object, and Rum-time error "91" showed.... "Object variable or with block variable not set. " is reporting while running the line: If dic.Exists(Subject) Then dic(Subject) = dic(Subject) + 1 Else dic(Subject) = 1, this is interesting cause i know this line works without Subfolder options..

Comment: Object variable or with block variable not set = dic is not set.

Comment: @lyricZZ see my updated answer an example- add your other codes to it one set at time while  testing it - make sure to use `Option Explicit`