# How to move an email between two folders on a shared mailbox?

Tags: vba, outlook

I managed to use the site to get code working on my personal mailbox.

When applied to a shared mailbox it doesn't work.

It works on personal mailbox moving from Inbox to Inbox Subfolder called Test

On the Shared Mailbox I need to move from Shared Mailbox Inbox to another folder called Complete. This is a folder in the shared mailbox and isn't a subfolder.

```
Sub MailmoveAP()
          
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim InboxItem As Object

    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = objNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("Test")

    For Each msg In ActiveExplorer.Selection
       msg.Move olFolder
    Next
            
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outlook Selecting a Subfolder in the SharedMailbox using GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851850/outlook-selecting-a-subfolder-in-the-sharedmailbox-using-getshareddefaultfolder)

Comment: So what problem are you trying to solve? That the subfolder is not accessible?

Answer (score 0):

The [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method requires two parameters, not a single one like the `GetDefaultFolder` does. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared Inbox folder). For example:

```
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev") 
 
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
   Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)
 End If 
 
End Sub 
 
Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
 CalendarFolder.Display 
End Sub
```

To get the `Complete` folder if it is located on the same level with `Inbox` you could use the `Parent` object of the Inbox folder and then get a subfolder. See how to [Enumerate folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-enumerate-folders) in Outlook and find the required one.

Comment: Can you help on the Parent object you have mentioned, what what i need to change on the below for it to find the complete folder.                   If objOwner.Resolved Then
    Set olTaskfolder = olNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, _
      olFolderInbox).Folders("Complete")                 This is where im getting a debug

Comment: Try using `olNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Complete")`